# How to find a gene sequence?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene

So I need to learn how to find the sequence of a gene, polyphenoloxidase. Please do not do this for me. Tell me how to approach the problem.

I have found : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene and searched for polyphenoloxidase and get a list of results.

Here is one PPO page: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/107923401
There is a FASTA sequence there under " NC_030099.1 Reference ASM98774v1 Primary Assembly" but I am not sure if PPO gene is there.

Comment: You need a gene sequence. What're you trying to accomplish? The list you get from the NCBI search notes PPO in different isoforms/types from different species. Perhaps you should first lock down your target organism and gene isoform. And so I click the top result, LOC107923401 (aka PPO-3; PPO-6; PPO-8) from Cotton. Scroll down to *Genomic regions, transcripts, and products* and click on the FASTA link. There is the raw sequence. Your FASTA and FASTQ files will be the result of NGS on your organism's genome.

Comment: @CKM advocado is my target organism.

Comment: If you want to blast that sequence, remove the subquery range it provides for you beside the sequence box.

Comment: @CKM Tried doing a Blast search for a PPO gene: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEFAULTS=on&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__3435__73885&DATABASE=GPIPE/3435/current

However there are no matches, which may be because it is a different species with a slightly different sequence? The genome I am searching is known to contain PPO.

Comment: It doesn't appear that anyone has sequenced it. See [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10408398.2016.1175416?src=recsys&journalCode=bfsn20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the sequence in the gene database, but it is perhaps easier to [search the nucleotide database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=polyphenoloxidase) if you are only looking for the sequence of nucleotides.

Comment: I used the sequence you helped me find to do a Blast search of a genome here: https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEFAULTS=on&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__3435__73885&DATABASE=GPIPE/3435/current     However there are no matches, which is may be because it is a different species with a slightly different sequence? The genome I am searching is known to contain PPO as advocados do brown.

Comment: @Dale It doesn't appear as though there is a whole genome sequence for avocado, yet.

Comment: What about: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=avocado

Comment: The existence of that page doesn't mean that the entire sequence is in the database.

Comment: @Dale There are a large number of ESTs for avocado and blasting against those (tblastn) with the tomato PPO protein sequence gave some hits.