# How to do a blast search for similar sequences?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene

Tried doing a Blast search for a PPO gene in an advocado genome: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEFAULTS=on&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__3435__73885&DATABASE=GPIPE/3435/current

However there are no matches, which may be because it is a different species with a slightly different sequence? The genome I am searching is known to contain PPO.

Comment: Once again, RTFM!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/74073/how-to-find-a-gene-sequence), there is no complete genome sequence for avocado as of yet, though people appear to be working on it.

However, there are a large number of [ESTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressed_sequence_tag) and doing a BLAST of their translations with the [tomato PPO sequence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/S40548.1) (tblastn) gives some hits.

[Here is a link to that BLAST.](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&USER_FORMAT_DEFAULTS=on&SET_SAVED_SEARCH=true&PAGE=Translations&PROGRAM=tblastn&QUERY=MSSSSSITTTLPLCTNKSLSSSFTTTNSSLLSKPSQLFLHGRRN%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20QSFKVSCNANNVDKNPDAVDRRNVLLGLGGLYGAANLAPLATAAPIPPPDLKSCGTAH%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20VKEGVDVIYSCCPPVPDDIDSVPYYKFPSMTKLRIRPPAHAADEEYVAKYQLATSRMR%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ELDKDPFDPLGFKQQANIHCAYCNGAYKVGGKELQVHFSWLFFPFHRWYLYFYERILG%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SLINDPTFALPYWNWDHPKGMRIPPMFDREGSSLYDEKRNQNHRNGTIIDLGHFGKEV%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DTPQLQIMTNNLTLMYRQMVTNAPCPSQFFGAAYLWVLNPSPGQGTIENIPHTPVHIW%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TGDKPRQKNGEDMGNFYSAGLDPIFYCHHANVDRMWNEWKLIGGKRRDLTDKDWLNSE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FFFYDENRNPYRVKVRDVLDSKKMGFDYAPMPTPWRNFKPIRKSSSGKVNTASIAPVS%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20KVFPLAKLDRAISFSITRPASSRTTQEKNEQEEILTFNKISYDDRNYVRFDVFLNVDK%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TVNADELDKAEFAGSYTSLPHVHGSNTNHVTSVTFKLAITELLEDIGLEDEDTIAVTL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IPKAGGEGVSIESVEIKLEDC&GAPCOSTS=11%201&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__3435__73885&DATABASE=GP/3435.73885/ESTs&MAX_NUM_SEQ=100&SHORT_QUERY_ADJUST=on&EXPECT=10&WORD_SIZE=6&MATRIX_NAME=BLOSUM62&COMPOSITION_BASED_STATISTICS=2&FILTER=L&FILTER=R&EQ_MENU=Enter%20organism%20name%20or%20id--completions%20will%20be%20suggested&BLAST_PROGRAMS=tblastn&SHOW_OVERVIEW=on&SHOW_LINKOUT=on&ALIGNMENT_VIEW=Pairwise&MASK_CHAR=2&MASK_COLOR=1&GET_SEQUENCE=on&NEW_VIEW=on&NUM_OVERVIEW=100&DESCRIPTIONS=100&ALIGNMENTS=100&FORMAT_OBJECT=Alignment&FORMAT_TYPE=HTML)

---

> However there are no matches, which may be because it is a different species with a slightly different sequence?

This is precisely the problem that BLAST was designed to solve.

Comment: how did you get that link to share your BLAST search?

Comment: @Dale There is a link on the page, near the top right, called "Bookmark".